# How get list Provides a handle to a directory entry in File System Access API?

Tags: javascript, native-file-system-api-js

I am get directory from file system and read data.

```
 try {
   const directoryHandle = await showDirectoryPicker({
         startIn: startIn.value,
   });
   for await (const [name, fileHandle] of directoryHandle) {
      directory.textContent =  directory.textContent + `${name} - ${fileHandle.kind}`
    }
 }
 catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
 }
```

then I want to get data from this directory and i want to get list all directoryes.

I am try this

```
const opfsRoot = await  navigator.storage.getDirectory(); 
const existingDirectoryHandle = await opfsRoot.getDirectoryHandle('Directory');
```

But i can't see my directory.

How can I get an already added directory ?
How can I get a list of added directories ?